# ScrollTo content not centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollto

I'm using a [jQuery ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin to scroll a page to a particular `<div>` or ID on the same page.

I currently have `#p1` as my main content, and `#p2` located offscreen to the right.

When I click on the link for `#p2`, my page scrolls left just fine; *but my `#p2` content is placed at the edge of the screen on the right.*

**I want to know how I can center mye `#p2` content regardless of screen resolution and distance from `#p1`**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col col-25">
        <a href="#p2">Typefaces</a>
    </div>

    <div class="offscreen">
        <div class="etc">
            <p id="p2">Some paragraph text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    max-width: 1600px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.offscreen {
    position: absolute;
    right: -1200px;
}

.etc {
    width: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.etc p {
    max-width: 450px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/s3R6U/1/

Making #p1 and #p2 both 50% width, float left.  And your container div 200% width.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="p1"><a href="#p2">Typefaces</a></div>
    <div id="p2">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 200%;
}

#p1, #p2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#p1 {
    text-align: left;
}

#p2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave - I used a method based off a similar approach. I added an additional div containing content and continued using divs based off of percentage widths and using background colors as stated from @Tans (above comment) to determine my content areas which helped out greatly.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I like the horizontal scrolling technique too... I never thought of it!

Answer (score 0):

I've done some changes kindly check whether they're correct or not

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid black">
<a href="#p2">Typefaces</a>
<div class="offscreen" style="border:1px solid black">
<div class="etc" style="border:1px solid black">
<p id="p2">Some paragraph text</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {

    max-width: 2600px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.offscreen {
    position: absolute;
    right: -750px;
    left: 100px
}

.etc {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.etc p {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Here I've added html with borders which will help you know a little bit more about location of text. Once you're done please remove those style attributes from `<div>`. In.offscreen if you'll do position to center then text will come to center or changing right and left of.offscreen can give you a better output.

I've verified in google chrome using **jsfiddle**. Kindly verify and let me know..

Comment: Thanks Tans - Your method of using borders helped out quite a bit. I used background colors to define my content areas and locations. I mentioned in Daves comment below that I used a method from both yours and Daves comments and also added an additional content div. Appreciate the help!